# Libraries must use the exact same versions specification

Tags: android, android-studio, duplicates, dependencies, android-support-library

I have created a project with :

```
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '27.0.2'
```

on dependecies I have this code:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    //        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    //    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2'
   compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.github.Kunzisoft:Android-SwitchDateTimePicker:1.4'
    compile 'com.eminayar.panterdialog:panter-dialog:0.0.2.1'
    compile 'com.github.polok:clicknumberpicker:0.1.2'
    compile 'com.roughike:bottom-bar:2.1.1'
    compile 'com.github.HotBitmapGG:RingProgressBar:V1.2.2'
    compile 'com.anjlab.android.iab.v3:library:1.0.44'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.6.2'
    compile 'com.github.10uroi:ToastOX:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.yarolegovich:lovely-dialog:1.0.4'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

I have error on 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2' and it says:

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version
>   specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found
>   versions 27.0.2, 24.2.1. Examples include
>   com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.0.2 and
>   com.android.support:percent:24.2.1

I've run gradlew -q dependencies app:dependencies --configuration compile
and this is the result:

[image]

How can I change it to 27 ?

**ATTENTION! I haven't used compile com.android.support:percent:24.2.1 it imports from com.github.polok:clicknumberpicker:0.1.2**

Answer (score 0):

Change-

```
com.android.support:percent:24.2.1
```

to-

```
com.android.support:percent:27.0.2
```

Comment: when I write it to dependencies it says it create conflict because it's from another import... as you see I haven't even used it on my gradle file please read the question...